# How to remove unwanted space from Ionic popover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Excuse me, but can you say me, please, what is that terrible footer in my popover?

Do you see this white line above last radio?

I don't want to see it. How to fix it?

[image]

```
<ion-popover-view>
    <ion-header-bar>
        <h1 class="title">Фильтр</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-radio ng-model="feedFilterLevel" value="0" ng-click="hideFilterPopover()">Все</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="feedFilterLevel" value="1" ng-click="hideFilterPopover()">По стране</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="feedFilterLevel" value="2" ng-click="hideFilterPopover()">По городу</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="feedFilterLevel" value="3" ng-click="hideFilterPopover()">Только контакты</ion-radio>
    </ion-content>
</ion-popover-view>
```

UPD: It is popover size. When I add another radios, size don't changes.
**How to change popover size or autosize it?**

Comment: Does that appear with any number of radios?

Comment: It seems that when you add ion-header-bar, you get this extra white space!!

Comment: Not, it is not ion-header-bar. It just not changes their height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this. But method are little strange. I tried to change class .popover, another classes, tried css via id. But works only it

```
<ion-popover-view style="height: 263px !important;">
```

If you have another answer, you're welcome.